# Does the Bone Selection Set Addon exist for Blender 2.8?

Tags: add-on, bones, selection-tools

The Blender Manual makes reference to an addon I desperately need, but can't find or load in the addon section of Preferences in Blender 2.82a.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/animation/bone_selection_sets.html

It's occurred to me that it might be an out of date doc, and that this addon might be something that existed in 2.79 at the time of the doc's writing. Does anyone know if an updated version of this addon is around? Or if there is another addon that does the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *yes*. But the reason I couldn't find this add-on in the Preferences window is because I unknowingly had the *Enabled Add-ons Only* box checked, meaning that searches that I was performing in the filter field weren't finding the add-on I was looking for. How funny is that?